# Integrate easyrtc server in tomcat

Tags: node.js, apache, tomcat, socket.io

i have a webapplication which is realized with servlets running on a tomcat server. This web application should also include a realtime videochat, for which i have choosen easyrtc. I have setup the easyrtc server already (via nodejs) and have changed the default port to 9090, to make it different from tomcat. It works just fine when running standalone, but i have problems to integrate it within the tomcat web application (since the easyrtc files are searched under the tomcat's port, which is 8080). I have read the manual but i have not yet found a solution for my requirement. Can someone point me in the right direction, probably providing some best practive? An iframe would be no alternative, since i need to share some javascript variables among the different pages on my web app.

Thanks in advance,
fredddmadison

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution:

When initializing the easyrtc on the client side, the following call can be used to set the url for webrtc:

```
easyRTC.setSocketUrl(some_url);
```

and everything works as expected.